# Ошибка при вводе дробных чисел в Java

Tags: java, double, scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        double x = sc.nextInt();
        double y = sc.nextInt();

        if (y < 2 * x){
            System.out.println("No");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }

        sc.close();
    }
}
```

в этом или даже самом примитивном коде по типу простого ввода дробных чисел выдает мне ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:943)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1598)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2263)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2217)
    at Main.main(Main.java:7)
```

ввод дробного числа осуществляю правильный, через точку. Нужна помощь с решением проблемы)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вы вводите дробное число, а пользуетесь методом целого числа **nextInt()**?
Воспользуйтесь методом для дробного числа **sc.nextDouble();**
В консоль вводите числа через запятую, а не точку. **2,22** а не **2.22**

Comment: Спасибо большое, не заметил)